# Pandas append list to list of column names

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm looking for a way to append a list of column names to existing column names in a DataFrame in `pandas` and then reorder them by `col_start` + `col_add`.

The DataFrame already contains the columns from `col_start`.

Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file.csv)

col_start = ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"]
col_add = ["Col_d", "Col_e", "Col_f"]
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns = list(col_add))]) #Add columns
df = df[[col_start.extend(col_add)]] #Rearrange columns
```

Also, is there a way to capitalize the first letter for each item in `col_start`, analogous to `title()` or `capitalize()`?

Comment: You already have a list so this would work fine: `df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns = col_add)]) `, also for the reordering would this just work: `df = df[col_start+col_add]`?

Comment: If you wanted to capitalise `col_start` then you can just do `col_start = [x.title() for x in col_start]` prior to using it for renaming

Comment: Are you asking to capitalise the column name or each data element in `col_start` columns?

Comment: @EdChum Only the column names :)

Comment: OK, so my answer should fully answer your question then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is nearly there, a couple things:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns = list(col_add))])
```

can be simplified to just this as `col_add` is already a list:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns = col_add)])
```

Also you can also just add 2 lists together so:

```
df = df[[col_start.extend(col_add)]]
```

becomes

```
df = df[col_start+col_add]
```

And to capitalise the first letter in your list just do:

```
In [184]:
col_start = ["col_a", "col_b", "col_c"]
col_start = [x.title() for x in col_start]
col_start

Out[184]:
['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C']
```

**EDIT**

To avoid the `KeyError` on the capitalised column names, you need to capitalise after calling `concat`, the columns have a vectorised `str` `title` method:

```
In [187]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_start + col_add)
df

Out[187]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col_a, col_b, col_c, Col_d, Col_e, Col_f]
Index: []

In [188]:    
df.columns = df.columns.str.title()
df.columns

Out[188]:
Index(['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D', 'Col_E', 'Col_F'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks! The code works as intended if I don't include the capitalization function. But if I do that, I get `KeyError: "["Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C"] not in index"`. It seems that it still wants to match the column names from the DataFrame when concatenating.

Comment: You'd have to do that after concatenating, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here what you want to do :

```
import pandas as pd

#Here you have a first dataframe
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

#a second one
d2 = pd.DataFrame([[8,7,3,8],[4,8,6,8]], columns=['col4','col5','col6', 'col7'])

#Here we can make a dataframe with d1 and d2
d = pd.concat((d1,d2), axis=1)

#We want a different order from the columns ?
d = d[col_start + col_add]
```

If you want to capitalize values from a column 'col', you can do

```
d['col'] = d['col'].str.capitalize()
```

**PS:** Update Pandas if ".str.capitalize()" doesn't work.

Or, what you can do :

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x:x.capitalize())
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it it and it works. Concatenation by `(columns = col_add)` worked better for me however because for my use `d2` is empty from start thus I don't have to define it separately. Appreciate the code for `capitalize()`!