# Python how to use name of a list as a column name in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of variables. I want to assign name of this list to a column in dataframe. The name `stress` and its elements keep on change.

```
stress = ['M13', 'M14', 'M15', 'M16', 'M17', 'M18']

outputlist = [ 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 18 ]  ### obtained from analysis

resultdf[stress] = outputlist ### I want to name the column same as list name.
```

I want something like this given below.

```
print(resultdf)
    stress
0    13
1    14
2    15
3    16
4    17
5    18
```

It results error when I attempt to do this because whole list values getting list in column header. How to achieve this.

Comment: This might be what you're looking to do: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934126/pandas-append-list-to-list-of-column-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934126/pandas-append-list-to-list-of-column-names)

Comment: No. I updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link [Correct Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018638/assigning-column-names-from-a-list-to-a-table)

Comment: Can you provide an example `outputlist` and how that maps to each column?

Comment: Question updated. Thanks

Comment: So nothing happens to this data: `['M13', 'M14', 'M15', 'M16', 'M17', 'M18']`?

Comment: If you're asking how to get the same of the `stress` variable, just put it in quotes `'stress'`. This question is very unclear, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for, although I'm not sure what the result data looks like:

```
>>> stress = ['M13', 'M14', 'M15', 'M16', 'M17', 'M18']
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16,17,18], [19,20,21,22,23,24], [25,26,27,28,29,30], [31,32,33,34,35,36]]
>>> result = {x: y for x,y in zip(stress, data)}
>>> result
{'M13': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'M14': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'M15': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 'M16': [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], 'M17': [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], 'M18': [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]}
```

Then you can convert the dictionary to a DataFrame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = pd.DataFrame(result)
>>> d
   M13  M14  M15  M16  M17  M18
0    1    7   13   19   25   31
1    2    8   14   20   26   32
2    3    9   15   21   27   33
3    4   10   16   22   28   34
4    5   11   17   23   29   35
5    6   12   18   24   30   36
```

## Edit (based on your update)

If you literally just want a single column with the variable as the name, put it in quotes:

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({'stress': outputlist})
>>> d
   stress
0      13
1      14
2      15
3      16
4      17
5      18
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needs to be a string. You are trying to use a variable as a column name. Instead write

```
resultd["stress"] = outputlist
```

Comment: This approach I am familar with. But I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: @Msquare Then in your question, put what you actually want to do. You're being vague.